# How to set up geographical email subdomains on Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-email

Can Google Apps mail support MULTIPLE geographical email subdomains? Such as:

- american.user@us.emaildomain.com
- new.zealand.user@nz.emaildomain.com
- french.user@fr.emaildomain.com

If so, how can this be implemented?

Is it also possible to lock down these subdomains so that they can only be accessed from certain IP addresses?

The reason we need it is that we need to demonstrate that users are in specific offices for a variety of boring but important regulatory compliance reasons.

Comment: This isn't possible, afaik

Comment: The question is too broad, actually it has three questions. The answer to the first question is Yes. The answer to the second question is in http://support.google.com/a. For the third question see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/Qxa9UZ8IeCg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about is a  managing information technology systems in a business environment. Probably it should be moved to Server Fault - StackExchange site.

Comment: @Rubén: This will be closed as off-topic at Server Fault. I think it's fine here, although it is perhaps too broad.

Comment: @Bit: Please limit yourself to a single question per question post.

Comment: @AlE. I don't think that it will be closed at Server Fault. That site has more than 2,700 questions about subdomains and 350 questions with the google-apps tag that are not closed.